# Avro Nested array exception

Tags: avro

I am trying to generate avro schema for nested array .
The top most array stores is the issue, however inner array Business is correct.

```
{"name": "Stores",
     "type": {
     "type": "array",
     "items": {
         "name": "Hours",
      "type": "record",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "Week",
          "type": "string"
        },
         {"name": "Business",
        "type":"array",
              "items": {"name":"Business_record","type":"record","fields":[
                  {"name": "Day", "type":"string"},
                  {"name": "StartTime", "type": "string"},
                  {"name": "EndTime", "type": "string"}
                        ]}
                    }
                ]
               
      }
      }
```

And the exception im getting is :

```
[ {
  "level" : "fatal",
  "message" : "illegal Avro schema",
  "exceptionClass" : "org.apache.avro.SchemaParseException",
  "exceptionMessage" : "No type: {\"name\":\"Stores\",\"type\":{\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"name\":\"Hours\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"Week\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"Business\",\"type\":\"array\",\"items\":{\"name\":\"Business_record\",\"type\":\"record\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"Day\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"StartTime\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"EndTime\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}}]}}}",
  "info" : "other messages follow (if any)"
} ]
```

I think something to do with [] Or{}  for the outer array fields but I'm not able to figure it out.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Avro and JSON Schema are unrelated. I'm not sure if you've got the two confused.

Comment: I have a json for which im trying to generate avro schema.

Comment: Right. This is unrelated to JSON Schema then. No worries =]

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake i was doing:
when added the **"type":**   for the nested array it worked for me.

```
 {
      "name": "Stores",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "name": "Hours",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
        {
              "name": "Week",
              "type": "string"
            },
          {
            "name": "Business",
            "type": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "name": "Business_record",
                "type": "record",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "Day",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "StartTime",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "EndTime",
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```